# AttributeError at /blog/create/blog-post

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am learning django but this error has made me sick.
I wanted to create a form to register a new blog post. But I get this weird error nobody seems to have got.
I'm really a begginer in django.
Here's the trace:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/create/blog-post

Django Version: 3.2.6
Python Version: 3.9.6
Installed Applications:
['blog',
 'django_summernote',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\My_Stuff\Blogistan\env\lib\site- 
    packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
    File "C:\My_Stuff\Blogistan\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", 
    line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
    File "C:\My_Stuff\Blogistan\blog\views.py", line 19, in BlogPostForm
    form = BlogPostForm(request.POST or None)
    File "C:\My_Stuff\Blogistan\blog\views.py", line 19, in BlogPostForm
    form = BlogPostForm(request.POST or None)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /blog/create/blog-post
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'POST'
```

Here's my console:

```
Internal Server Error: /blog/create/blog-post
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\My_Stuff\Blogistan\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\My_Stuff\Blogistan\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\My_Stuff\Blogistan\blog\views.py", line 19, in BlogPostForm
    form = BlogPostForm(request.POST)
  File "C:\My_Stuff\Blogistan\blog\views.py", line 19, in BlogPostForm
    form = BlogPostForm(request.POST)
AttributeError: 'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'POST'
```

My `views.py`:

```
def BlogPostForm(request):
    form = BlogPostForm(request.POST)
    return render(request, 'create_post.html', {
        'form': form})
```

I'm trying to integrate ``` django-summernote`` My ``` forms.py```:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from blog.models import BlogPost
from django_summernote.widgets import SummernoteWidget

class BlogPostForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'content_html': SummernoteWidget(),
        }
```

My `models.py`:

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=360)
    urlpattern = models.CharField(max_length=360)
    content_html = TextField(max_length=12000)
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

My template:

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block body %}
    <form class="post-form" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>  
    </form>
{% endblock body %}
```

Can someone help me with this.
Your help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to rename your view function `BlogPostForm` because it overrides the imported form with the same name.

The error occurs because the view function is called recursively with the argument `request.POST` which is a `QueryDict`, therefore the error:

```
AttributeError: 'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'POST'
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help.
This is my first question on Stackoverflow. Didn't expect such a quick answer.
I'am so bad at giving variable names.
What I did to solve this was using `django.views.generic.edit.CreateView` and this is my view now.

```
class BlogPostCreateView(CreateView):
   form_class = BlogPostForm
   model = BlogPost
   template_name = 'create_post.html'
   success_url='/'
```

This is the form.

```
class BlogPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('label_suffix', '')
        super(BlogPostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    content_html = forms.CharField(widget=SummernoteWidget)
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = '__all__'
        label_suffix = ''
        labels = {
            'content_html': '',
            'title': 'Title',
            'urlpattern': 'Slug'
        }
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
            }),
            'urlpattern': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
            }),
        }
```

This works very well and styling this was easier than ever